# How to add Socket (Messenger) into background

Tags: android, service, messenger, android-workmanager, socketcluster

I created a messenger application which works with sockets. So I want to add it in background. In background the socket will hear income messages in background and show notifications. So I want to do it with `WorkManager`. Is it the best way and will this work? Or there are another ways to do this? Thanks. If you interested I'm using `SocketCluster`.

Comment: We do something similar in an app my team has developed. We ended up using a foreground service to keep our socket alive: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Ok I can use foreground service. But what if I don't want to show a notification always? I only want to show notification when someone sends me a message.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, haven't been on here in awhile. Unfortunately, if you make your service a foreground service, it has to always show the notification, there is no way to dismiss it. This works good for the voice app my team maintains, but I can see how that might not be ideal for a messenger app. If the foreground notification is a deal-breaker, you could leave your service as non-foreground and use GCM/FCM for when the app is not in the foreground. We do this for the messenger application my team maintains.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `FCM` for this. Using Sockets for maintaining persistent TCP connections can be bad from a battery perspective. If you *must* do this, use a foreground `Service`.

Comment: Ok I can use foreground service. But what if I don't want to show a notification always? I only want to show notification when someone sends me a message.